# Sign XML with .p12 certificate keyEntry error null

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to sign XML with .p12 certificate utilizing the code bellow, but I am getting an error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.security.KeyStore$PrivateKeyEntry.getCertificate()" because "keyEntry" is null
at xmlCreateSignature/xmlCreateSignature.xmlSignature.main(xmlSignature.java:38)**

Line 38 is `X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();`

Any help is appreciated:

Here is my code:

```
package xmlCreateSignature;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.crypto.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dom.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.C14NMethodParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.TransformParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Base64;


public class xmlSignature {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.ignoreLineBreaks", "true");
    
    // Load the XML document
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("./certDir/request.xml"));
    
    // Load the certificate
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream("./certDir/4300648_identity.p12"), "DAL00MATIAN".toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry((String) ks.aliases().nextElement(), new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("DAL00MATIAN".toCharArray()));
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

    // Create the XML signature
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), doc.getDocumentElement());
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
    Reference ref = fac.newReference("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null), Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)), null, null);
    SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA256, null), Collections.singletonList(ref));
    KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
    X509Data x509d = kif.newX509Data(Collections.singletonList(cert));
    KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(x509d));
    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

    // Sign the XML document
    signature.sign(dsc);
    SignedInfo signedInfo = signature.getSignedInfo();

    // Get the references from the signed info
    List<Reference> references = signedInfo.getReferences();

    // Process each reference and encode the digestValue to Base64
    for (Reference reference : references) {
        // Get the digestValue as a byte array
        byte[] digestValue = reference.getDigestValue();

        // Encode the digestValue to Base64
        String base64DigestValue = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digestValue);

        // Output the Base64-encoded digestValue
        System.out.println("Base64-encoded DigestValue: " + base64DigestValue);
    }

    // Save the signed XML document

    // Save the signed XML document
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File("./certDir/request_response.xml")));

}
}
```

Comment: Please mark the line in your code where the exception occurs. Also the stack trace of the exception would be helpful.

Comment: @Robert: there's only one call to that method and the stacktrace isn't going to add anything. OP: make sure your ks file contains/uses the alias 'cert12'; if it is in PKCS12 format, which the suffix .p12 usually implies but not necessarily, Java's 'alias' is the PKCS12 'friendly name'. The simplest way is `keytool -list -keystore certDir/cert12.p12`.

Comment: I have updated the alias with (String) ks.aliases().nextElement() and it works now. But the problem is that it generates invalid xml. The requirements require the digestValue to be Base 64 encoded. ENcoding int after it is being signed does not makes a lot of difference.